Bootstrap css misbehaving
I am using bootstrap classes to style my application but in certain range of screen width , it is misbehaving.Like gap between flex elements increases,alignment changes and so on.
<Col xs={12} md={5} xl={4} className='order-xl-0 m-0 p-0'>
   <div className=' workStepContainer d-flex flex-column row-gap-1'>
      <div className='d-flex w-100 justify-content-between pt-0 '>
         <div className='w-45p p-3 flexCenter'>
           <img src='/assets/specialists/work1.png' alt='image' className='h-80px w-80px '/>
         </div>

        <div className='w-50 d-none d-xl-flex bg-white ps-2 pb-2 '>

            <div className=' px-3  workDarkContainer '>
               <div className='fw-bold fs-2 text-white'>01.</div>
                  <div className='lightGreenText  lh-sm'>Choose specialist</div>
            </div>

            <div className='triangle-right'/>
        </div>

        <div className='d-flex justify-content-end d-xl-none bg-white  blueContainer w-50 ps-2 pb-2 pt-0 '>
           <div className=' p-3   workDarkContainer '>
               <div className='fw-bold fs-2 text-white'>01.</div>
               <div className='lightGreenText  lh-sm'>Choose specialist</div>
           </div>
      </div>
                                   
    </div>

named classes are used for color only here.

in given pic , in certain range unwanted margin appears on top of blue div ,then it dissappers.

expected UI
without giving the margin explicitly , it is apperaing here . what can be the reason for this?

You HTML isn't quite standard HTML. That's a pity because now people familiar with normal HTML, like me, can't help you. Why not put the output of your code in the question? Also, all the CSS is missing. This means we cannot hope to reproduce your problem, which would most likely be the first step in solving it.

Just checking, have you closed the col tag ? Or inspect the website if all is building in the correct way.
Your second element from the list it's smaller, like it was build inside the first one.
If it's not the case, can you try putting all the list structure with the css used. Thanks

Please use answers to answer an answerable question, not for comments. Your observation about the second list element is well spotted though.

Yes, i know... But i cant until i have 50 reputation :') I'll update the content when i have more info.
